# NuGet Dependencies not copying with VS2013 and AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, unity-container, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just took my quickly hacked together MVC4 project and added dependency injection via the Unity.MVC4 nuget package.

It all works fine when I run the site locally, but when I deploy it to Amazon via elastic beanstalk, the Microsoft.Practices.Unity dll is not copied over to the bin folder. I've checked the properties on the dlls and they are set to copy to the output directory. I even tried just copying them into a folder called dll-refer and making sure those are marked as content and set to copy local, but this folder also isn't copied over.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: Same problem. System.Web.Optimization.dll is missing in the web package. And sometimes it is deployed. Sometimes restarting VS helps. No clue what is happening. It's just started without any change to the configuration on VS setup.

Answer (score 0):

For me, making sure the references that are missing after deploy were set to "Copy Local" in the project.

To do so, click on the reference item under the "References" folder in your project. Then switch to the "Properties" tab (or right click and select "Properties" from the context menu). Make sure the "Copy Local" option is set to "True". Then redeploy your application.

There are some references that will not need to have the "Copy Local" option set to "True". These are the references included in the .NET Framework.